# How to change BottomNavigationBar icons on click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, bottomnavigationview

Is there a way to change icons when they are clicked on BottomNavigationView? I tried using a selector like that but it didn't work, or I just don't know how to implement it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home2" android:state_checked="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/like" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/like2" android:state_checked="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/play" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/play2" android:state_checked="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/alarm" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/alarm2" android:state_checked="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/user" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/user2" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

LIKE THIS

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a selector for each image.
So your `home_selector.xml` would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home2" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```